# Having problems deploying a Rails app to Fedora 8 w/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger

I'm using Capistrano and have everything configured.  The weird issue I have is that before, I got a nice Passenger error saying what was wrong (I hadn't fully uploaded my vendor/rails directory).  After I do that, however, I'm now getting the general Rails `We're sorry, but something went wrong` 500 error instead of the Passenger error page.  My production log shows nothing (only that the log was created).  Apache logs show nothing.  I don't get why I'm no longer seeing the Passenger error that tells me exactly what is wrong; fixing the error Passenger was complaining about shouldn't prevent it from getting there, should it?

Can anyone help me?

FYI I'm running several PHP-based applications on the same server, with the rails app set as a subdomain (e.g. railsapp.mydomain.com).  The full stack is:

- Fedora Core 8
- Apache 2.2.9
- MySQL 5.0.45
- Rails 2.3.4
- Passenger 2.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues at hand:

1. You're log file isn't writable by Passenger. Passengers runs as Apache. So make sure the webserver has the correct rights to write to the log/ directory.
2. You are probably missing a gem, database or configuration file. Can you start a console session?

   ./script/console production

Comment: I am able to start a console session.  I figured it out, it was using the wrong socket to MySQL (for some reason I changed it and committed it to SVN but Capistrano didn't pull it down)